# PostgreSQL: Combine Count and DISTINCT ON

Tags: postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, distinct

Given this table

```
| id | name  | created_at                 |
| 1  | test  | 2015-02-24 11:13:28.605968 |
| 2  | other | 2015-02-24 13:04:56.968004 |
| 3  | test  | 2015-02-24 11:14:24.670765 |
| 4  | test  | 2015-02-24 11:15:05.293904 |
```

And this query which returns only the rows id 2 and id 4.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (documents.name) documents.*
FROM "documents"  
ORDER BY documents.name, documents.created_at DESC
```

How can i return the number of rows affected? Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON (documents.name) documents.*) FROM "documents"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an outer query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) *
    FROM documents
    ORDER BY name, created_at DESC
    ) alias
```

Comment: As soon as you start adding more columns than "name" it doesn't work, FYI. Distinct ON will take each individual column for uniqueness, where distinct col1,col2,col3 checks the entire combination.